# Flutter:Build Failed Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\"myUsername"\Desktop\test1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin']
  >   Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionGradleServices.createOutputFilesRepository().
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 32s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: did you try running flutter packages get?

Comment: also try flutter clean and then rerun the project

Comment: the second one worked

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade your jdk to version 8, it might work. Let me know if it works